# Getting a value based on conditions from multiple rows

Tags: mysql

This is what my data looks like.

[image: This is what my data looks like]

I need to get the `info_id` value based on conditions from two different rows. Using the above data as an example, I want to check if an `info_id` is associated with a row where (field_id = 298 and value = 213) AND with a row where (field_id = 299 and value = 216). In this case, the query should return 35.

Comment: `AND ALSO`? Don't you mean `OR`?

Comment: Well, since `AND ALSO` is not valid SQL syntax, `OR` will do what you need. If that's not what you mean you need to clarify exactly what you _do_ want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing this...

```
SELECT
  t1.info_id
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2
  ON t1.info_id = t2.info_id
WHERE
  (t1.field_id = 298 AND t1.value = 213) AND
  (t2.field_id = 299 AND t2.value = 216);
```

Output:

```
| info_id |
|---------|
|      35 |
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4628/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field_id, value where (field_id = 298 AND value = 213) OR (field_id = 299 and value 216);
```

did i miss something, or like that?
Basically you wish to retrieve two rows with one row had field_id=298 and another row had field_id=299 right?

Comment: Not it's AND, not OR, I want to get info_id where two of the coditions meet.

Comment: wait, is it possible a single column in a row had two values? (for numeric of course). Maybe we need to look your schema. and example case.

Comment: It's possible, the info(info_id) has multiple fields(field_id)